# How do i make Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working a personal project for learning rails. Its a task management app, the task has states, todo, in progress and done. After tinkering for many days i got trello like drag and drop functionality working in between task states but its not changing the state.

here is my javascript code,

```
var ready;
var id = $(this).attr("task_id");
ready = function(){
    // call sortable on our div with the sortable class
    $('#sortable1').sortable({
      connectWith: ".connected",
      dropOnEmpty: true
    });
    $('#sortable2').sortable({
      connectWith: ".connected",
      dropOnEmpty: true
    });
    $('#sortable3').sortable({
      connectWith: ".connected",
      dropOnEmpty: true
    });
};

$(document).ready(ready);
/**
 * if using turbolinks
 */
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

So now when i drag and drop item from sortable1(which is "to do") to sortable2(which is "in progress") or sortable3(which is "done"), i want it to make the call to the change route

```
  resources :tasks do
    member do
      put :change
    end
  end
```

and change the state based on the params,

```
def change
    @task.update_attributes(state: params[:state])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to tasks_path, notice: 'Task updated' }
    end
end
```

I am new to javascript and AJAX in general. Detailed description on how it should work, what i can do to solve the problem better, with links to respective topic for better understanding would help.

Here is my views

```
<%= link_to 'New Task', new_task_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<br>
<br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 tasks">
    <h2 class="text-xs-center">Todo</h2>
    <ul id="sortable1" class="connected sortable list droptrue" state="to_do">
    <% @to_do.each do |task| %>
    <li draggable="true">
    <div class="<%= task.state == 'to_do' ? 'card card-outline-info' : task.state == 'in_progress' ? 'card card-outline-success' : 'card card-outline-warning'  %>" style="max-width: 20rem;" task-id="<%= task.id %>">
      <div class="card-header action-box">
        <div class="text-xs-left">
          <strong><%= link_to task.title, edit_task_path(task)%></strong>
        </div>
          <div class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">
            <i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
    <%end%>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 tasks">
    <h2 class="text-xs-center">In Progress</h2>
    <ul id="sortable2" class="connected sortable list droptrue" state="in_progress">
    <% @in_progress.each do |task| %>
    <li draggable="true">
    <div class="<%= task.state == 'to_do' ? 'card card-outline-info' : task.state == 'in_progress' ? 'card card-outline-success' : 'card card-outline-warning'  %>" style="max-width: 20rem;" task-id="<%= task.id %>">
      <div class="card-header action-box">
        <div class="text-xs-left">
          <strong><%= link_to task.title, edit_task_path(task)%></strong>
        </div>
          <div class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">
            <i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
    <%end%>
    </ul>
  </div>


  <div class="col-lg-4 tasks">
    <h2 class="text-xs-center">Done</h2>
    <div>
    <ul id="sortable3" class="connected sortable list droptrue" state="done">
    <% @done.each do |task| %>
    <li draggable="true">
    <div class="<%= task.state == 'to_do' ? 'card card-outline-info' : task.state == 'in_progress' ? 'card card-outline-success' : 'card card-outline-warning'  %>" style="max-width: 20rem;" task-id="<%= task.id %>">
      <div class="card-header action-box">
        <div class="text-xs-left">
          <strong><%= link_to task.title, edit_task_path(task)%></strong>
        </div>
          <div class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">
            <i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
    <%end%>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

sortable1 has "state='to_do'" attribute , sortable2 has "state='in_progress'" and "state='done'". I dont even 100% know why i added state attribute, just thought maybe it will help while ajax calling haha.

Comment: This isn't really the kind of question that Stack Overflow is supposed to deal with. There is a mountain of examples online explaining how AJAX works. I suggest you start by searching with your favorite search engine for "AJAX tutorials."

Comment: There are plenty of ajax tutorials out there. Asking for detailed instructions that could be found in any of those tutorials (check out the jquery docs page or the mozilla developer network) is off topic for stackoverflow. If you run into a more specific issue then that would be a better fit.

Comment: If in doubt, always try one of the Rails Guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to send an ajax/xhr request when you drop an item.  Here's a sample (in Coffeescript) similar to what is documented at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

```
$.ajax(url: "/change").done (html) ->
  $("#results").append html
```